# Access nodejs app on koding.com

Tags: node.js, cloud, virtual-machine

I'm trying to upload two node.js files to koding.com and run them.

index.js contains:

```
var server = require("./server");

server.start();
```

And server.js

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

function start() {
  function onRequest(request, response) {
    console.log("Request received.");
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
  }

    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(6665, '0.0.0.0');
    console.log("Server has started.");
}

exports.start = start;
```

I typed in vm terminal `jstq@vm-0:~$ node Web/IkapNodeJS/index.js`
it gives me `Server has started.`
If im going to http://jstq.kd.io/IkapNodeJS/index.js - i see index.js contains.
When im adding :6665 to that url - url not found.

How do i see page with hello world?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running your application on `6665`, the you would access it with http://jstq.kd.io:6665/. You should see your `Hello world` there.

Node does not run like a cgi script; you don't point to the file to run it, you run it with a process (`node`). When the server is running on a specific port, the content will be available on any address/hostname that points to that machine so long as you specify the proper port.

HTH,
Aaron

Comment: i got `Error 312 (net::ERR_UNSAFE_PORT): Unknown error.` when click that url.

Comment: It **should** work like this, there appears to be an issue with koding.com right now. Here's a discussion on the topic: https://koding.com/Activity/nodejs-4. Also, the wiki: http://kwiki.koding.com/wiki/Nodejs

Comment: btw, if appears to work on private VMs, I'm only currently having this issue on the shared environment.